# from simple list adapter to custom array adapter

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, adapter

I have a class which retrives data from my database and displays it in a listview using simple adapter

```
public class ViewExs extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://www.lamia.byethost18.com/get_all_ex.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "ID_exercise";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "ID_exercise";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_exs);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditProductActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        /*  // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);*/
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewExs.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ViewExs.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.item_list_3, new String[] {TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

i want to use a custom adapter rather than the simple adapter .. here is my custom adapter

```
 public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;
  TextView textView;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_list_3, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_3, parent, false);

    final TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pid);
textView.setText(values[position]);

return rowView;
  }
  }
```

how i do this part of code

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ViewExs.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.item_list_3, new String[] {TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

in the custom adapter ?

can someone help please ?

Comment: `MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(ViewExs.this, new String[] {TAG_NAME});`

Comment: @PedroOliveira but this will not retrive from database ..

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `MySimpleArrayAdapter` in your method and set the adapter -

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(ViewExs.this, 
                new String[] {TAG_NAME});

                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: do i change something in the adapter ? because i got an error on run time

Comment: not an error but it will not retrieve from data base

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your arrays of values is String[] values, then

```
    MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(
                    ViewExs.this,values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: do i need to change something in the adapter ? cuz i got an error while running

Comment: no sorry its not an error but it will not retrieve from the data base it will just print ID_exercise

Answer (score 0):

Hi I used a custom array adapter like the one below, it's just a sample. But I hope it helps. It displays data that was sent to it using an ArrayList from an fragment where it is displayed.

```
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Movie> movies;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> movies) {
        super(context, R.layout.movie_layout, movies);
        this.context = context;
        this.movies = movies;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View movieView = convertView;

        if (movieView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            movieView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_layout, parent, false);
        }
        movieView.setTag(movies.get(position));
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) movieView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView txtDate = (TextView) movieView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) movieView
                .findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        txtTitle.setText(movies.get(position).MovieTitle);
        txtDate.setText("Date Viewed: " + movies.get(position).dateViewed);
        ratingBar.setIsIndicator(true);
        ratingBar.setNumStars(movies.get(position).rating);
        ratingBar.setRating(movies.get(position).rating);
        return movieView;
    }
}
```

The fragment

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment {

    Movie movie;
    MovieAdapter adapter;
    MovieSelectedListener callBack;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

        ListView movieList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieList);

        movieList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView movie = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                String title = movie.getText().toString();
                callBack.onMovieSelected(title);
            }
        });

        if (getArguments() != null)
            movie = (Movie) getArguments().getSerializable("Movie");
        Log.v("PASSED", "Got here");
        adapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), movie.movies);
        movieList.setAdapter(adapter);
        movieList.setLongClickable(true);
        movieList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    final View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity());
                dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this movie?");
                dialog.setTitle("Alert Message");
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                TextView movie = (TextView) view
                                        .findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                                String title = movie.getText().toString();
                                callBack.onDeleteSelected(title, adapter);

                            }
                        });
                dialog.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }
                        });
                dialog.show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public interface MovieSelectedListener {
        public void onMovieSelected(String movie);

        public void onDeleteSelected(String movie, MovieAdapter adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ;
        try {
            callBack = (MovieSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement MovieSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    public void sortTitle() {

        adapter.sort(new Comparator<Movie>() {
            public int compare(Movie lhs, Movie rhs) {
                return lhs.MovieTitle.compareTo(rhs.MovieTitle);
            }
        });
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void sortDateViewed() {

        adapter.sort(new Comparator<Movie>() {
            public int compare(Movie lhs, Movie rhs) {
                return lhs.dateViewed.compareTo(rhs.dateViewed);
            }
        });
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void sortRating() {

        adapter.sort(new Comparator<Movie>() {
            public int compare(Movie lhs, Movie rhs) {
                return ((Integer) lhs.rating).compareTo(rhs.rating);
            }
        });
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```